# Problem retrieving certificates for self signed jar

Tags: java, certificate, code-signing

I have a jar that's self signed with keys that I generated using the java keytool. At runtime I attempt to retrieve the certificates with the following code:

```
ProtectionDomain pd = MyApplication.class.getProtectionDomain();
Certificate[] cert = pd.getCodeSource().getCertificates();
```

This works fine when my jar is used in a standalone, command line java application. However, when I use this jar in a web application that's deployed in Weblogic server, the getCertificates() call returns null. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the container has been configured to unzip the .WAR file, so it is loading your classes from the WEB-INF/classes directory instead of the .WAR file directly. So the code source is a directory so it doesn't have a certificate.